# php csv export abnormally betweent Mac and Windows system

Tags: php, csv

csv export code：

```
public function export_csv(){
        if(($id = $this->get_input('resultId')) == '') {
            $this->msg('error');
        }
        $result = call_mod_func('admin/activity_mod', 'get_result', array($id));
        $str = "name,email,mobile,tel" . PHP_EOL;
        $str = iconv('utf-8', 'gb2312', $str);  

        foreach($result['rows'] as $row) {
            $name = iconv('utf-8', 'gb2312', $row['name']);
            $email = $row['email'];
            $mobile = $row['mobile'];
            $weixinid = iconv('utf-8', 'gb2312', $row['weixinid']);

            $str .= $name . ',' . $email . ',' . $mobile . ',' . $weixinid . PHP_EOL;
        }

        $filename = date('Ymd', gettime()) . '.csv';  

        header("Content-type:text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=".$filename);
        header('Cache-Control:must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0');
        header('Expires:0');
        header('Pragma:public');
        echo $str;
    }
```

In Mac system, when open it only has one column.

In Windows system, when open it has four column.

Could you tell me how to modify the code? Can it be compatible with multiple systems?

Comment: Why don't you use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function?

Comment: have you tried to use the `;` (semicolon) as delimiter? Don't know if the Mac interpretes it a the correct delimiter by default but windows should.

Comment: How do you open it? MS Excel is kind of strict how the delimiters and such are set (it requires semicolon in MS Excel 2008 for Mac). If you use LibreOffice, you can choose which character is supposed to be the delimiter. Also, you might want to enclose your strings with (double) quotes in case it contains a delimiter (e.g. "Last name, First name").

Comment: use fgetcsv , fputscsv